# GPS on DragonBoard 410c in Windows 10 IoT Core Preview

Tags: gps, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10, dragonboard

Is on-board GPS confirmed to be enabled on the DragonBoard 410c in Windows 10 IoT Core Preview?

I used this Geolocation sample as a test:

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Geolocation

It returns a location, but the source is "IP Address" and the accuracy is very low, so I'm guessing it is not getting any GPS data.

Has anyone gotten a different result?

Thank you.

Comment: I have read on a forum somewhere that the onboard GPS antenna is a bit weak and that using the GPS indoors may be a bit hit or miss. However you can add an external antenna. See [Adding U.FL Antenna Connectors to DragonBoard™ 410c and Validating GPS on Android and Linux](https://developer.qualcomm.com/qfile/29467/lm80-p0436-42_c_add_ufl_ant_validate_gps_on_android_linux.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I can conform that it does work. I have connected an active antenna to the boards with my own power circuit, feeding the antenna 5.0v and AC coupling with the U.Fl connector and the GPS works on IOT. I get Satellite as source when I use the uwp geolocation.